# Autohotkey Hotkey trigger another hotkey

Tags: loops, autohotkey, hotkeys

Again, I am new to the Autohotkey section, a problem I face right now. Ok, let me explain some on this as below.

```
a::
  loop
  {
    ; do something
    break
  }
  Send,{b}
return

b::
  ; do something
  Send,{a}
return
```

When "a" pressed, it is fined to call "b" activity, but after that, inside "b" it couldn't call "a" again. Why?

Comment: Prefix both key labels with `$` like `$a::` and `$b::`

Comment: Prefix **$** will only make me can't even call another hotkey function.. i want to keep calling each other when the hotkey is send within the function..

Comment: $a::
Send,{y}
Sleep,100
Send,{b}
return

$b::
Send,{x}
Sleep,100
Send,{a}
return 


this only bring me to send yb when "a" pressed and send xa when "b" pressed...

Comment: Don't use `{}` to send a letter key, just `send a`. Also try all methods: `sendplay` or `sendEvent` or `sendInput`

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but you could also add a label to both hotkeys each, and use `gosub`  or `goto` (doesn't matter which one in your case, since there is a `return` after it anyways) INSTEAD of `send`

Comment: or, you do not call `a` from `b`, but instead put the body of `a` in another, second loop

Comment: finally, please consider using proper intendation for better readability: both for you and the stack com

Comment: Related: [Toggle a key with hotkey in autohotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19232303/3357935)

Answer (score 1):

Use [GoSub](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gosub.htm).
Example:

```
!z::
    MsgBox, z
return

F10::
    Gosub, !z
return
```

Answer (score 0):

With the newest Autohotkey Release (v1.1.22.09) following code creates a infinite loop calling itself:

```
a::
  loop
  {
    MsgBox % "A Hotkey"
    break
  }
  Send b
return

b::
  MsgBox % "B Hotkey"
  Send a
return
```

I assume you stripped out the "do something" code, where the real problem is located.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with label.

test:
a::
loop
{
; do something
break
}
Send,{b}
return

b::
; do something
goto, test
return